# single level to multi-level dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe with many columns

```
pd.DataFrame(data=np.random.rand(10,4),columns=['a||b','a||c','b||d','b||e'])



     a||b      a||c      b||d      b||e
0  0.920209  0.913427  0.269640  0.305458
1  0.015503  0.537648  0.668155  0.456014
2  0.535996  0.908736  0.262496  0.950372
3  0.271928  0.187117  0.501474  0.351366
4  0.362223  0.308811  0.948894  0.649872
5  0.255547  0.264383  0.755152  0.339240
6  0.908696  0.014974  0.179077  0.956830
7  0.912979  0.912669  0.062033  0.518936
8  0.705435  0.209669  0.398958  0.131777
9  0.897860  0.420016  0.172101  0.294667
```

I would like to derive from this dataframe a new multilevel dataframe having columns
'a' and 'b on the first level, 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e' on the second.

I can split separately the column names:

```
df.columns[0].split('||')
```

and have a tuple of values as column name, e.g. ('a','b')
How do I group back together the columns that have the first (or maybe the second) element of the tuple in commmon?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`split`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.split.html) with parameetr `expand=True`:

```
ddf.columns = ddf.columns.str.split('\|\|', expand=True)
print (ddf)
          a                   b          
          b         c         d         e
0  0.248756  0.163067  0.783643  0.808523
1  0.625628  0.604114  0.885702  0.759117
2  0.181105  0.150169  0.435679  0.385273
3  0.575710  0.146091  0.686593  0.468804
4  0.569999  0.645701  0.723341  0.680671
5  0.180917  0.118158  0.242734  0.008183
6  0.360068  0.146042  0.542723  0.857103
7  0.200212  0.134633  0.213594  0.973156
8  0.858330  0.533785  0.434459  0.187193
9  0.288276  0.627167  0.355706  0.729455
```

EDIT:

```
np.random.seed(456)

ddf = pd.DataFrame(data=np.random.rand(10,4),columns=['a||b||e','a||c','b||d','b||e'])

ddf.columns = ddf.columns.str.split('\|\|', expand=True)
print (ddf)
          a                   b          
          b         c         d         e
          e       NaN       NaN       NaN
0  0.248756  0.163067  0.783643  0.808523
1  0.625628  0.604114  0.885702  0.759117
2  0.181105  0.150169  0.435679  0.385273
3  0.575710  0.146091  0.686593  0.468804
4  0.569999  0.645701  0.723341  0.680671
5  0.180917  0.118158  0.242734  0.008183
6  0.360068  0.146042  0.542723  0.857103
7  0.200212  0.134633  0.213594  0.973156
8  0.858330  0.533785  0.434459  0.187193
9  0.288276  0.627167  0.355706  0.729455
```

---

```
mux = ddf.columns.to_frame().dropna(axis=1).values.tolist()
print (mux)
[['a', 'b'], ['a', 'c'], ['b', 'd'], ['b', 'e']]

ddf.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(mux)
print (ddf)
          a                   b          
          b         c         d         e
0  0.248756  0.163067  0.783643  0.808523
1  0.625628  0.604114  0.885702  0.759117
2  0.181105  0.150169  0.435679  0.385273
3  0.575710  0.146091  0.686593  0.468804
4  0.569999  0.645701  0.723341  0.680671
5  0.180917  0.118158  0.242734  0.008183
6  0.360068  0.146042  0.542723  0.857103
7  0.200212  0.134633  0.213594  0.973156
8  0.858330  0.533785  0.434459  0.187193
9  0.288276  0.627167  0.355706  0.729455
```

Comment: works great! thanks. This is likely the final answer. Is there a way to drop unused levels? if I have a||c||d and g||h my new columns will be a,g, first level, c and h on second, while on the third I would have d and nan, how to drop or fill with empty string that nan?

Comment: Hmmm, it is hard question. Give me some time

Comment: great now it is perfect